# Customize install-log location in Visual studio setup projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

The SetUp projects from Visual Studio will have their installation logs under temp folder with the name format like " %temp%\ .log "

Can I have some customization done here, so that these installation logs will go to a specific folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the location that MSI logs are written to by invoking MSIEXEC with the [`/L <logfilepath>`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_SetLogging) argument. If you cannot change the command line arguments (such as if the MSI is invoked by a setup executable), [edit the registry to change the default log location](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300).